# Controlling both players on NBA Jam

Tags: xbox-360, nba-jam-2010

I started to play NBA Jam on Xbox 360. I'm playing against COM in Classic Campaign mode. There are 2-on-2 games in this mode and I can only control one of my players. The other player is automatically controlled by COM. Is there a setting to let me control both of my team players?

Comment: @Mepher I updated my answer from yesterday now that I've actually gone back and looked at the game.  Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:  I looked last night.  It seems that you CAN have two human players in Classic Campaign mode.  The problem is that once you start a classic campaign, the players in it are locked.  If you start a new Classic Campaign with two players the entire time, you should be able to play on a team.  You cannot, however, add a second player on the fly.